# Can I use one model inside of a different model in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

Can I use another Model inside one model?

Eg.

```
<?php
class Form extends AppModel
{
    var $name='Form';
    var $helpers=array('Html','Ajax','Javascript','Form');
    var $components = array( 'RequestHandler','Email');

    function saveFormName($data)
    {
        $this->data['Form']['formname']=$data['Form']['formname'];
        $this->saveField('name',$this->data['Form']['formname']);
    } 

    function saveFieldname($data)
    {
        $this->data['Attribute']['fieldname']=$data['Attribute']['fieldname'];
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: excuse me? helpers and components in a Form model that saves attributes? this is all over the place, neither mvc nor cake.

Comment: Brad takes the cake here... CakePHP, if you use it right, will automatically link the instances together, via associations.. There's really no point in instantiating another instance of the model if it's already there... If you are unable to associate the models directly, then looking at instantiating a new model might be an option.

Comment: `TableRegistry::get('Products')` for cakephp 3. See @tarikul05 answer

Answer (score 120):

Old thread but I'm going to chime in because I believe the answers to be incomplete and lacking in "why". CakePHP has three ways to load models. Though only two methods work outside of a Controller, I'll mention all three. I'm not sure about version availability but this is core stuff so I believe they'll work.

**[`App::import()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-App.html#_import)** only finds and `require()`s the file and you'll need to instantiate the class to use it. You can tell `import()` the type of class, the name and file path details.

**[`ClassRegistry::init()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-ClassRegistry.html#_init)** loads the file, adds the instance to the object map and returns the instance. This is the better way to load something because it sets up "Cake" things as would happen if you loaded the class through normal means. You can also set an alias for the class name which I've found useful.

**[`Controller::loadModel()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Controller.html#_loadModel)** uses `ClassRegistry::init()` as well as adds the Model as a property of the controller. It also allows `$persistModel` for model caching on future requests. This only works in a Controller and, if that's your situation, I'd use this method before the others.

Comment: A similar set of statements explained by gwoo himself: http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/msg/794c451038c0c798

Comment: Using `Controller::loadModel()` in a model throws a warning about the static call: `Non-static method Controller::loadModel() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

Comment: @Matt the method Controller::loadModel() is meant to be called within your current controller like `$this->loadModel('aModel');`

Comment: Beware these answers are no longer applicable to CakePHP v3+

Answer (score 26):

You can create instances of other models from within any model/controller using one of these two methods.

If you're using Cake 1.2:

```
App::import('model','Attribute');
$attr = new Attribute();
$attr->save($dataYouWantToSavetoAttribute);
```

If you're using Cake 1.1:

```
loadModel('Attribute');
$attr = new Attribute();
$attr->save($dataYouWantToSavetoAttribute);
```

Comment: App::import() is not very good for models. $attr = ClassRegistry::init('Attribute') should be used.

Comment: Actually my form has fields(Attributes) like associations

Comment: @drHannibalLecter: ClassRegistry::init() will return an instance of the model which will use more memory. Won't it be more messy?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: As far as I know, it will return an already existing instance of a model, it won't create a new one if there is one in the class registry. Besides, what else would it return if not an instance of the model?

Comment: @drHannibalLecter:

App::import()

`Finds classes based on $name or specific file(s) to search. Calling App::import() will not construct any classes contained in the files. It will only find and require() the file.` in API documentation(which is not good). I don't understand why API docs recommend use of ClassRegistry::init() over App::import()..!!  For cakephp 2.0 and above,  `App::uses()` is good.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: Because it's easier to use? You need an instance of the model anyway, so why not use the one cake gives you? Creating one on your own with `new` is pretty much a code smell in cake. If you're not talking about models, but your own custom classes/libraries, that's a different matter entirely.

Comment: Even after a couple of years, I still say there's no good or bad way of doing it. Use `App::import()` if you need "fresh and untouched" instance of a model and use `ClassRegistry::init()` if you want an existing instance of model from registry. Difference lies in the need for your case. For example, with `ClassRegistry::init()` in a behavior `afterFind()` you wont get full set of model relationships if you had used `'contains'` in your `find()` call. `App::import()` allows you to create a fresh instance to get all default information about the model in question. That's just one case.

Answer (score 16):

An obvious solution everyone missed is to create an [association](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) between two models, if appropriate.  You can use it to be able to reference one model from inside another.

```
class Creation extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Inventor' => array(
            'className'  => 'Inventor',
            'foreignKey'  => 'inventor_id',
        )
    );

    public function whoIsMyMaker() {
        $this->Inventor->id = $this->field('inventor_id');
        return $this->Inventor->field('name');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good for database wise, however in php you can't execute functions in that other model through this :(

Comment: `$this->Inventor` should be an instance of the `Inventor` model; as long as your methods are public you should be able to invoke them just fine.  If you're experiencing different behavior I suggest posting a new question.

Comment: Hmmmm now i'm checking the doc i see what you're saying is indeed true. I thought this behaviour was only reserved for java/.net... Thanks for pointing out, this should actually be the best answer :)

Answer (score 11):

In CakePHP 1.2, it's better to use:

```
ClassRegistry::init('Attribute')->save($data);
```

Comment: How is it good? Won't it use more memory because it creates an instance of the model?

Answer (score 4):

This will do simply

```
<?php
   class Form extends AppModel
    {
       //...
          $another_model = ClassRegistry::init('AnotherModel');
       //...  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In CakePHP 3 we may use [TableRegistry::get(modelName)](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#getting-instances-of-a-table-class)

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$itemsOb = TableRegistry::get('Items');
$items = $itemsOb->find("all");
debug($items);
```

Comment: Or if the models are associated. i.e. Products -> Categories, you can call it directly. `$this->Categories` from within the ProductsTable

Comment: @styks nice, that did it! I think this suggestion deserves to be a standalone answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Model_B inside Model_A, add this line at the beginning of Model_A file:

```
App::uses('Model_B_ClassName', 'Model');
```

and then you will be able to use it inside Model_A. For example:

```
$Model_B = new Model_B_ClassName();
$result = $Model_B->findById($some_id);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var $uses = array('ModeloneName','ModeltwoName');
```

By using `$uses` property, you can use multiple models in controller instead of using `loadModel('Model Name')`.

```
App::import('model','Attribute');
```

is way to use one model into other model. Best way will be to used association.

Comment: Note that the `$uses` attribute only works in controllers; as urdesh mentions use associations in models.

Comment: He is asking to use a Model inside another Model