# Get original associations after using Containable behavior in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

**Background:** CakePHP 2.6.3. A pretty stable app. New behavior (`MyCustomBehavior`) created to output some extra info. 
I have a Model `MyModel` acting as `Containable` (defined in `AppModel`) and then `MyCustom` (defined in `MyModel`). `MyCustomBehavior` is written in a way that it needs to work with the Model's associations with other Models in my app.

**Problem:** Whenever I contain related models in my `find()` call of `MyModel`,  I cannot get a complete list of `MyModel` associations because `Containable` behavior unbinds the models that are not contained.  However, if I don't set `contain` in my `find()` options or set `'contain' => false` everything works as expected.

***Sample `MyModel->belongsTo`***

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'MyAnotherModel' => array(
        'className' => 'MyAnotherModel',
        'foreignKey' => 'my_another_model_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Creator' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Approver' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'approver_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Status' => array(
        'className' => 'Status',
        'foreignKey' => 'status_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);
```

***Sample `find()`***

```
$this->MyModel->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(...),
    'conditions' => array(...),
    'contain' => array('Approver', 'Status')
));
```

***Result of `MyModel->belongsTo` in `MyCustomBehavior::beforeFind()`***

```
$belongsTo = array(
    'Approver' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'Status' => array(
        ...
    ),
);
```

***Expected `MyModel->belongsTo` in `MyCustomBehavior::beforeFind()`***

```
$belongsTo = array(
    'MyAnotherModel' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'Creator' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'Approver' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'Status' => array(
        ...
    ),
);
```

**Obvious solution:** One dumb way to solve the problem is to simply set `Containable` behavior in `MyModel` instead of `AppModel` to control the order of loading the behaviors, i.e., `public $actsAs = ['MyCustom', 'Containable']`. This solution is not the best because there may be other behaviors in other models that depend on `Containable`, so the order of `Containable` needs to set in each model in app explicitly and hope that I didn't break the app somewhere.

A similar(related) question was asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10421701/1369473) but has no answers.

Need a more robust solution that can address the needs of `MyCustomBehavior` without having to make changes in rest of the app and looking out for any unexpected behavior.

Comment: Well, I thought someone would post an answer that's better than mine or at least point me to a potential issue with the solution that I believed was perfect. Since there hasn't been much activity on this post, I mark my solution as accepted until someone can offer a better solution with good reasoning. I wouldn't mind changing my accepted solution if it's worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attempt 1 *(Imperfect, error prone)*:**

One way to recover all the original associations is to call

```
$MyModel->resetBindings($MyModel->alias);
$belongsToAssoc = $MyModel->belongsTo;    // will now have original belongsTo assoc
```

However, this approach it may fail (SQL error `1066 Not unique table/alias`) to work correctly if I had used `joins` in my find call (using default `alias`) to explicitly join to an already associated model. This is because `Containable` will also attempt to join all these tables restored by `resetBindings()` call resulting in join being performed twice with same alias.

**Attempt 2 *(perfect<sup>#</sup>, no known side effects<sup>##</sup>)*:**
Further digging through the core `Containable` behavior and [docs](https://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-Model.html#) led me to object `$MyModel->__backOriginalAssociation` and `$MyModel->__backAssociation` (weird enough that `ContainableBehavior` never used `$__backContainableAssociation` as the variable name suggests) that was created and used by this behavior to perform `resetBindings()`. So, my final solution was to simply check if `Containable` is enabled on my modal (redundant in my case because it is attached in `AppModel` and is never disabled or detached throughout the app) and check if the object is set on the model.

```
// somewhere in MyCustomBehavior
private function __getOriginalAssociations(Model $Model, $type = 'belongsTo') {
    if(isset($Model->__backAssociation['belongsTo']) && !empty($Model->__backAssociation['belongsTo'])) {   // do an additional test for $Model->Behaviors->enabled('Containable') if you need
        return $Model->__backAssociation[$type];
    }

    return $Model->$type;
}

public function beforeFind(Model $Model, $query) {
    // somewhere in MyCustomBehavior::beforeFind()
    ...
    $belongsToAssoc = $this->__getOriginalAssociations($MyModel, 'belongsTo');    // will now have original belongsTo assoc
    ...
return $query;
}
```

`$__backAssociation` holds model associations temporarily to allow for dynamic (un)binding. **This solution can definitely be further improved by merging results of `$Model->belongsTo` and `$Model->__backAssociation['belongsTo']` (or `hasMany`, `hasOne`, `hasAndBelongsToMany`) to include any models that were bound on the fly.** I don't need it, so I will skip the code for merging.

---

<sup>***<sup>#</sup> Perfect*** for my own use case and my app setup.

**<sup>##</sup> No side effects** were found in my testing that is limited by my level of expertise/skill.

**Disclaimer: My work in this post is licensed under [WTF Public License(WTFPL)](http://www.wtfpl.net/)**. So, do what the f**k you want with the material. Additionally, I claim no responsibility for any financial, physical or mental loss of any kind whatsoever due to the use of above material. Use at your own risk and do your own f**king research before attempting a copy/paste. Don't forget to take a look at [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) because SO says **"user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required." (check the footer on this page. I know you never noticed it before today! :p)**</sup>