# cakephp how to use another table here

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

This code is using a table `Users` to update a field `myField`. Now I have a need to use a table called `Customer` and update a field called `customerRelation` to 1. How would I do that?

```
var $name = 'Answers';

    var $components = array('RequestHandler');

    var $uses = array('Answer','Field','User');


    function checkAll() {

        $user = $this->User->read(null,$this->Auth->user('uid'));
        $this->User->saveField('myField', 'TEST');

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980556/using-another-model-inside-one-model-in-cakephp) The methods are the same to load a model in the controller. I hope you use a model for the needed table.

Answer (score 2):

```
ar $name = 'Answers';

var $components = array('RequestHandler');

var $uses = array('Answer','Field','User','Customer');


function checkAll() {

    $user = $this->User->read(null,$this->Auth->user('uid'));
    $this->User->saveField('myField', 'TEST');
    $this->Customer->saveField('customerRelation ', 1);

}
```