# CakePHP new rows upload

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a problem here and I wish you could help me.
So, I have a controller x_controller.php, with its model.

I have some simple text inputs and selects, but also some file inputs, plus there's a button[Add 1 more file] which generates another file type input. How would I upload each of these file inputs in another table, like myFiles?

And each file should be a new row in myFiles.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the other model to your x_controller using the `$uses` like this:

```
var $uses = array('ThisModel','SomeOtherModel');
```

To save to the other mdoel use:

```
$this->SomeOtherModel->save($someOtherModel);
```

Comment: $uses is not considered very good practise. You should load another model only when needed. Look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4753244/829198

Answer (score 0):

```
loadModel('MyFile');
$myFile = new MyFile();
//write your code to upload file, then add to database
$myFile->save($saveYourUploadedFilePath);
```