# cakephp use another model inside current model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I know I can use another model inside a controller by doing [`$this->loadModel("MyModel")`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/992/loadModel), but how do I do this inside another Model? I tried to use loadModel but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use one model inside of a different model in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980556/can-i-use-one-model-inside-of-a-different-model-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Easier is:

```
$my_model = ClassRegistry::init('MyModel');
```

More details:
[Can I use one model inside of a different model in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980556/using-another-model-inside-one-model-in-cakephp)

Comment: This is the best way. If you use `App::import` or `App::uses` with model constructor then will be problem e.g. with TranslateBehavior. Reason: `DboSource` class use `ClassRegistry::getObject` to get model and read virtual fields. So to prevent using two instances of the same model use this solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code to export a model that is not associated with the current model in any way:

```
App::import('Model', 'MyModel');
$my_model = new MyModel();
```

If `MyModel` is associated with current model you could use the chaining e.g. `$this->SomeModel->MyModel`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import anything.
Just do this:

```
$my_model = new MyModel();
//Then
$my_model->read(null,$id);
```