# Using a model in a different controller with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have some controllers in my Cake application, namely `servers` and `users`. I want to write a simple API and have a controller called `ApiController`. Within this controller I want to use both the `servers` and `users` models.

I'm very new to Cake, but not MVC in general. From what I've picked up so far Cake will automatically use the `servers` model in the `ServersController` controller, I don't know how to explicitly use a model from a certain controller.

Also, I want the API requests to only serve JSON without any HTML markup. I have a default layout that defines the header/footer of all my site pages and that gets outputted when I request an API function as well as the JSON from the view. How can I stop the layout from being output and instead just serve the view?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to declare the `$uses` property in your controller see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#controller-attributes

The `$uses` attribute states which model(s) the will be available to the controller:

```
<?php
class ApisController extends AppController{
    public $uses = array(
        'User',
        'Server'
    );
}
```

Also you don't appear to be following Cake naming conventions where controller names are plural (`Apis` or `Servers`) and model names are singular (`Api` or `Server`). These names should also be in CamelCase. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html for more information

Regarding the JSON, there is an Ajax layout you can use to help you server JSON requests. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts for more information on how to achieve this.

Comment: Alternatively you can use $this->loadModel('Model'); to load models on the fly in case you only need them in certain portions of code. You can then communicate with the models normally (i.e. $this->Model->doSomething();) as if it were their own controller.

Comment: Don't you just love Cake so much?

Comment: It's sped up the work process on the applications I've used it with greatly. Definitely my preferred framework.

Comment: If you want `ApisController` to still be able to use the model `Api` in the normal `$this->Api` way you need to include it in the `$uses` array: `public $uses = array('Api', 'User', 'Server');`.

Answer (score 2):

Yottatron's answer is spot on, as is Nick Savage's. It's important to know the differences between the different ways to load a model, which is succinctly covered in following comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753244/117413

Personally, I stay away from overloading the global `$uses` array since it's very rare that I need a reference to all the model objects at a global level (and it's just bad practice to overload it, as per the Cake docs here: https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html#components-helpers-and-uses )

Comment: I agree with you on the `$uses` global shouldn't need to be done in AppController and on the odd occasion in controllers only say when you need access to a model that isn't associated.