# CakePHP, access model method from different model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

how can i access method `$this->someModel->find('all')` when im in different model form example:

```
class DevicesController extends AppController {
     public function add(){
         $departments = $this->Department->find('all', array(
            'fields'     => array('id', 'mac')
     ));
     $this->set(compact('departments'));

    .....
    .....
}
```

right now there is error because `$this` doesn't "see" `Department`

what i need to do to make it happen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980556/can-i-use-one-model-inside-of-a-different-model-in-cakephp/4753244#4753244

Comment: Are Device and Department model related via relations in the models?

Comment: no, in `Depratment` i store only names of department

Comment: Answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980556/can-i-use-one-model-inside-of-a-different-model-in-cakephp/4753244#4753244

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If models are not related, try this way:

```
$this->loadModel('Department');
$departments = $this->Department->find('all', array(
            'fields'     => array('id', 'mac')
     ));
$this->set(compact('departments'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the models are in fact related (and properly set up so in the models), it would be

```
$this->Device->Department->...
```

otherwise use loadModel() as documented.

Answer (score 0):

u can't just use loadModel() because it is controller's method.
if your models aren't related u can do this like that

```
$this->ModelName = ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');
$this->ModelName->find...
```

if they are related just use

```
$this->ModelName->find...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for loading different models on a controller. 
public $uses = array('ModelName1', 'ModelName2')
$this->ModelName1->find()........