# use unassociate model in another model with condition in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have this model named `UserRecord` which is not directly related to `UserLimit` model.

```
class UserRecord extends AppModel {


public function afterSave($created,$option=array()){ 

    $id=$this->data['UserRecord']['id'];
    $user_rec = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('UserRecord.id' => $id)));
    $uid = $user_rec['UserRecord']['user_id'];
    $UserLimit = ClassRegistry::init('UserLimit');

    $user_limit = $UserLimit->find('first', array('conditions' => array('UserLimit.uid' => $uid)));

}
}
```

Is it the right way to use another unassociate model with `find` query and `conditions` in `CakePHP`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use one model inside of a different model in CakePHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4753244/2666289)

Comment: I have make correction to the code. It's working.

[More Details][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980556/can-i-use-one-model-inside-of-a-different-model-in-cakephp

Comment: If you have found your answer in the possible duplicate, please close/flag your answer as duplicate, it will help people searching for a solution in the future ;)